# My observer is not logging out the user when password is changed

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, customer-account

1) I registered my extension at `app/etc/modules/Bmg_Golo.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Bmg_Golo>local</Bmg_Golo>
        <active>true</active>
    </modules>
</config>
```

2) My **config.xml** is at `app/code/local/Bmg/Golo/etc/config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Bmg_Golo>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Bmg_Golo>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <Bmg_Golo>
                <class>Bmg_Golo_Model</class>
            </Bmg_Golo>
        </models>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <controller_action_postdispatch_customer_account_resetpasswordpost> 
                <observers>
                    <Bmg_Golo>
                        <class>Bmg_Golo/observer</class>
                        <method>logout</method>
                    </Bmg_Golo>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_postdispatch_customer_account_resetpasswordpost>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

3) I created an observer at `app/code/local/Bmg/Golo/module/Observer.php`

```
<?php
/**
* 
*/
class Bmg_Golo_Model_Observer
{
    public function logout($observer) {
        $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
            if ($session->isLoggedIn()) {
                Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->logout();
            }
    }

}
?>
```

Now when i log in as customer and change password. Its not logging out

Comment: More appropriate solution would be to observe predispatch event on controller rather than allow to login only to logout right after. It makes no sense at all.

Comment: I am new to magento It will be great if you tell me in detail

Comment: Should it be like this? 
<frontend>
  <events>
   <controller_action_predispatch> 
    <observers>
     <bmg_golo>
      <type>model</type>
      <class>bmg_golo/observer</class>
      <method>logout</method>
     </bmg_golo>
    </observers>
   </controller_action_predispatch>
  </events>
 </frontend>

Comment: Have you not just tried to clear the session completely e.g. Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->clear(); which should kill off all sessions include customer and they will need to login again

Comment: I think my observer method is never been called :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/201548/observer-method-is-not-getting-called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check that your code in app/etc/modules/Bmg_Golo.xml file is not correct.

It should be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <[Package]_[Module]>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
    </[Package]_[Module]>
  </modules>
</config>
```

Apart from that rest of the code is looking fine.

Please let me know if it worked.